# Android dependencies with libraries

Tags: java, android, dependencies, aviary, okhttp

So a library I want to use depends on OkHttp 1.2.1, and I am currently using the newest version of OkHttp 2.0.

This naturally results in a compilation error as multiple dex files are generated for the same classes.

I don't quite want to manually update the library, and I do require the newest version of OkHttp.

Is there a way to somehow prioritize the latest version of OkHttp for any of my classes, and have the library continue to use the old version?

Comment: can you explain what you mean "by using the latest version for your classes and have the library use the older version"? an example would help us understand what you mean

Comment: What are you using for your builds? Ant? Eclipse? Gradle/Android Studio? Something else?

Comment: Which library? We OkHttp folks want everyone to jump on 1.6.0 which is an easy upgrade and which is forwards-compatible with 2.0.0.

Comment: It's Aviary (https://www.aviary.com/), they are also using a very outdated version of picasso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just renaming the namespace for the newer version of the library and including it!